# How to update custom domain DNS to point Firebase keeping the custom domain address?

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting

I have purchased a custom domain from Google and configuring it's DNS to point to Firebase URL. It is showing 404 error.

[image: Google Domain]

Comment: Since you blurred out some of the more important information, there is not a lot we can do here. If you feel uncomfortable sharing that information (I'm not sure why, since the information in the DNS is publicly accessible anyway) you should reach out to Firebase support.

Comment: I already emailed my query at firebase support with full info.